# error of using cvCaptureFromFile in android local part when building the xxx.so!~~

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I was do as what  the Opencv2.2 said([this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android)) ;
now,i can use builded static opencv libs to build my needed xx.so file,and than android program,and it works.but when i use the function cvCaptureFromFile,there is a error like below
during build.

$ $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build
Compile++ thumb: facedetection <= /cygdrive/e/workspace/Recognization1_0/jni/hus
t_iprai1104_jni_FaceDetectedJNI.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libfacedetection.so
/cygdrive/d/OpenCV-2.2.0/android/build/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a
(cap.o): In function `cvCreateVideoWriter':
cap.cpp:(.text.cvCreateVideoWriter+0x16): undefined reference to`cvCreateVideoW
riter_Images(char const*)'
cap.cpp:(.text.cvCreateVideoWriter+0x20): undefined reference to `cvCreateVideoW
riter_Images(char const*)'
/cygdrive/d/OpenCV-2.2.0/android/build/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_highgui.a
(cap.o): In function`cvCreateFileCapture':
cap.cpp:(.text.cvCreateFileCapture+0x2): undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCap
ture_Images(char const*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/cygdrive/e/workspace/Recognization1_0/obj/local/armeabi/libfacedetec
tion.so] Error 1

it said can not find cvCreateFileCapture_Images(char const*),what can i do????
  is that opencv2.2 actrually not suport video process when cmake or make???

Answer (score 0):

HighGUI is actually responsible for constructing the UI elements for the OPENCV NATIVE UI , for displaying the images etc , and it is also used for grabbing frames etc, as this cannot be compiled in android because unavailability of the UI libraries in the JNI library as well as , in android the UI is created in java , so HIGHGUI cannot be incorporated to the OPENCV library , if incorporated also u cannot use it in full swing ,

so for reading Video file or grabbing the frame from camera, use android java framework (eg: camera.Preview callback to get raw YUV frames) , then use it to construct the IplImage and use it for processing.

Hope this solves ur problems..